# Sending a HTTP POST request from Python (trying to convert from PHP)

Tags: php, python, http-headers, porting

I am trying to convert this code snippet from PHP to Python (programming newbie) and am finding difficulty in doing so:

The PHP that I am trying to convert is as follows:

```
$fp = fsockopen($whmcsurl, 80, $errno, $errstr, 5);
if ($fp) {
$querystring = "";
foreach ($postfields AS $k=>$v) {
$querystring .= "$k=".urlencode($v)."&";
}
$header="POST ".$whmcsurl."modules/servers/licensing/verify.php HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header.="Host: ".$whmcsurl."\r\n";
$header.="Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header.="Content-length: ".@strlen($querystring)."\r\n";
$header.="Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
$header.=$querystring;
$data="";
@stream_set_timeout($fp, 20);
@fputs($fp, $header);
$status = @socket_get_status($fp);
while (!@feof($fp)&&$status) {
$data .= @fgets($fp, 1024);
$status = @socket_get_status($fp);
}
@fclose ($fp);
}
```

It corresponding Python code that I wrote is as follows:

```
fp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                fp.connect(("my ip", 80))
                if (fp):
                        querystring = ""
                        #print postfields
                        for key in postfields:
                                querystring = querystring+key+"="+urllib.quote(str(postfields[key]))+"&"
                header = "POST "+whmcsurl+"modules/servers/licensing/verify.php HTTP/1.0\r\n"
                header+="Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
                header+="Content-length: "+str(len(querystring))+"\r\n"
                header+="Connection: close\r\n\r\n"
                #header+=querystring
                data=""
                request = urllib2.Request(whmcsurl,querystring,header)
                response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
                data = response.read()
```

Here, I am faced with the following error:

```
request = urllib2.Request(whmcsurl,querystring,header)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 200, in __init__
    for key, value in headers.items():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

So I am guessing that Python is expecting a dictionary for the header. But the PHP sends it as a string.

May I know how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are overcomplicating things, by quite some distance. Python takes care of most of this for you. There is no need to open a socket yourself, nor do you need to build headers and the HTTP opening line.

Use the [`urllib.request`](https://docs.python.org/library/urllib.request.html) and [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/library/urllib.request.html) modules to do the work for you:

```
from urllib.parse import urlopen
from urllib.request import urlopen

params = urlencode(postfields)
url = whmcsurl + 'modules/servers/licensing/verify.php'
response = urlopen(url, params)
data = response.read()
```

`urlopen()` takes a second parameter, the data to be sent in a `POST` request; the library takes care of calculating the length of the body, and sets the appropriate headers. Most of all, under the hood it uses another library, [`httplib`](https://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html), to take care of the socket connection and producing valid headers and a HTTP request line.

The POST body is encoded using `urllib.parse.urlencode()`, which also takes care of proper quoting for you.

You may also want to look into the [external `requests` library](https://requests.readthedocs.io/), which provides an easier-to-use API still:

```
import requests

response = requests.post(whmcsurl + 'modules/servers/licensing/verify.php', params=params)
data = response.content  # or response.text for decoded content, or response.json(), etc.
```

Comment: So, in this case, I don't need to put write code for the header? Is that what is handled by `params = urlencode(postfields)`

Comment: The headers are handled entirely by `urlopen()`. Because you send a body (a second parameter) a POST is sent, and the content type and content length headers are set. The Host header is always set.

Answer (score 2):

your headers should look like this

```
headers = { "Content-type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" };
```

Comment: There is much more wrong here. The `POST ... HTTP/1.0` line is not a header and does not need to be constructed in any case, for example.