# Using regex to convert XML representation to Dictionary in python

Tags: php, python, regex, porting

I sent a POST message in python based on [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18074616/sending-a-http-post-request-from-python-trying-to-convert-from-php). Once this is done, I get a resultant XML representation that looks like this from the website:

```
<status>Active</status>
<registeredname>MyTestName</registeredname>
<companyname>TEST</companyname>
<email>mytestemail@gmail.com</email>
<serviceid>8</serviceid>
<productid>1</productid>
<productname>Some Test Product</productname>
<regdate>2013-08-06</regdate>
<nextduedate>0000-00-00</nextduedate>
<billingcycle>One Time</billingcycle>
<validdomain>testing</validdomain>
<validip>XX.XX.XXX.XX</validip>
<validdirectory>/root</validdirectory>
<configoptions></configoptions>
<customfields></customfields>
<addons></addons>
<md5hash>58z9f70a9d738a98b18d0bf4304ac0c6</md5hash>
```

Now, I would like to convert this into a python dictionary of the format:

```
{"status": "Active", "registeredname": "MyTestName".......}
```

The corresponding PHP code from which I am trying to port has something like this:

```
preg_match_all('/<(.*?)>([^<]+)<\/\\1>/i', $data, $matches);
```

My correponding Python code is as follows:

```
matches = {}
matches = re.findall('/<(.*?)>([^<]+)<\/\\1>/i', data)
```

'data' is the XML representation that I receive from the server. When I run this, my 'matches' dictionary remains empty. Is there something wrong in the regex statement? Or am I wrong in using `re.findall` in the first place?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You **really** don't want to do this with regular expressions. There are plenty of answers here on SO that show how to do this with a decent XML parser instead.

Comment: Is there no top-level XML tag, btw? Is this the whole document?

Comment: yes.. There is no top-level XML tag. this is the whole document. So I am guessing its not an XML doc per se

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove leading/trailing `/`s from the regular expression. No need to escape `/`. Specify `flags=re.IGNORECASE` instead of trailing `i`.

```
matches = re.findall('<(.*?)>([^<]+)</\\1>', data, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(dict(matches))
```

Using raw string, no need to escape `\`.

```
matches = re.findall(r'<(.*?)>([^<]+)</\1>', data, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(dict(matches))
```

Both codes print:

```
{'status': 'Active', 'companyname': 'TEST', ...}
```

### non-regex alternative: lxml

Used `lxml.html` instead of `lxml.etree` because `data` is incomplete.

```
import lxml.html
print({x.tag:x.text for x in lxml.html.fromstring(data)})
```

Comment: Both these prints the output as dictionaries. How do I store them as dictionaries? Because when I give `print matches`, I get `[('status', 'Active'), ('companyname', 'test'),....]`

Comment: @i.h4d35, Try `result = dict(matches)`.